# Appending country names to route feature class using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, spatial-join, feature-class

I have a polyline feature class made up of multiple segments. This feature class overlays a polygon feature class representing the countries through which this polyline is going. For each segment, I would like to add an attribute containing all the countries through which the segment crosses, delimited by a comma for example.

I have tried a Spatial Join, using the polyline as the target and the polygon as the join feature. Unfortunately this has resulted in null values for the country attribute.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that one feature can cross multiple countries.  It'll explain the null values. You can try to split these features first (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/editing-existing-features/ways-to-split-a-line-feature.htm#GUID-A60F71A1-CEEE-4D20-92AB-CD4528D01DCD) and then do a spatial join.

I think splitting features will improve your data quality too.